# Is it possible to store a prompt's message into a variable?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to store a prompt's message into a variable?

i.e.

```
var userAnswer = parseInt(prompt('What is ' + questions[i][0] + ' ' + questions[i][1] + ' ' + questions[i][2] + '?'));
```

How would you go about storing the prompt's message as a string inside a variable and/or array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: build the message first:

```
msg = 'What is' + blah blah blah;
^^^
var userAnswer = parseInt(prompt(msg));
                                 ^^^
```

Comment: Could you store the message from the prompt in a variable after you have used the prompt rather than defining a variable for you to use in the prompt?

Comment: no, because that string is built/discarded when the prompt function returns. there is NO provision in prompt() to return anything OTHER than the answer.

Comment: you create some custom prompt, then you can. @JoelPendleton. please accept answer.